# Editing and overwriting a local file in js

Tags: javascript

I have a file stored in a folder name `testfolder` my local disk.

The file text would be something like the below

```
Apples are red. <colour = red/> latitude 13.124165
```

Is it possible to get the content of this file in to a variable and then do some adjustment and overwite it?

```
fopen("C:\testfolder\test.text", 0);
 var cont = ``; //get content in to a variable?
 //update cont
fwrite(file, cont);
```

Comment: That's PHP, not JavaScript.

Comment: @Tushar Thanks. That was something I found while googling. http://www.careerride.com/JScript-read-and-write-file.aspx I'm wondering if this is possible in js?

Comment: @Tushar No, I am not using NodeJS.

Comment: You should explain more about your case, for example, the javascript is running in a page on a remote web server, or is just open locally on your pc? Do you want the script to open and read this file automatically when you load the page?

Comment: @MarioAlexandroSantini Thanks. This is only to be used locally on my PC. Yes, I want the script to open and read this file automatically when the page opens.

Comment: @MarioAlexandroSantini So basically I need to open a file from my local disk and to get the content of this file in to a variable and then to overwrite it. As I mentioned in my previous comment this is only to be used locally on my PC.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript - read local text file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14446447/javascript-read-local-text-file)

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to get the content of this file in to a variable and then do some adjustment and overwite it?

**Short answer:** Yes.

**Long answer:** Yes. I understand you mean synchronously. For example in node you can read and write files synchronously with [fs.readFileSync()](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfilesync_file_options) and [fs.writeFileSync()](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefilesync_file_data_options), respectively.

**Simple example:**

```
user@host:~$ echo "Hello foo" > file.txt                                                               │
user@host:~$ node                                                                                      │
> var fs = require("fs");                                                                                 │
undefined                                                                                                 │
> var str = String(fs.readFileSync("file.txt"));                                                          │
undefined                                                                                                 │
> str = str.replace("foo", "bar");                                                                        │
'Hello bar\n'                                                                                             │
> fs.writeFileSync("file.txt", str);                                                                      │
undefined                                                                                                 │
> process.exit(); // (Or simply type ctrl+d)                                                              │
user@host:~$ cat file.txt                                                                              │
Hello bar
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read a file from the server, then you need to send an Ajax request from the client, and listen to it on the server.

However, if you want to read a file from the user's computer, then that's (for obvious reasons) not possible.